# Change input element look

Tags: css

Is it possible to make an input HTML element with a value make to look just like a text in a div using CSS? Make the border disappear and make the background color of the input same as the page backgound color.

Comment: you mean input textbox that is not empty, or all input textboxes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand correctly: yes.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/zaK7j/

**Test CSS:**

```
input, div {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: transparent;
    font: 13px sans-serif
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" value="Yes." />
<div>Yes.</div>
```

Comment: can't you target type='text' with a pseudo selector?

Comment: Yes you can, but some of the older IEs (I forget which ones, but it may just be IE6, so it's fine) don't understand them. They're mighty handy though!

Comment: in chrome, how can you remove the "inner shadow" and the "highlight when focussed" from the input field?

Comment: @ChristianStrang: `input:focus { outline: 0; }`.

Answer (score 2):

```
input[type=text], textarea {background:none;border:0;padding:0;margin:0;}
```

Will reset your input and also your textarea.

Edit: Note that this works in IE7 and above.

Comment: `background:none` probably makes more sense here than `background: transparent`. I always forget about `background:none` (+1).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the CSS

```
input{
    border: none;
}
```

Comment: This would make all inputs lose their border, you need to use an attribute selector

Comment: Yeah, this is the most basic html/css combo.

Answer (score 0):

Your htlm like this i presume :

```
<div>
    <input type="text" value="some text"/>
</div>
```

And your css :

```
div {
    background-color: olive;
}
input[type=text] {
    border: none;
    background-color: olive;
}
```

Comment: Your selector will reset all inputs - select only those with text value in.